# Sort populated record in sails waterline

Tags: postgresql, waterline, populate, sails-postgresql

I created a Sails application with two models Publication and Worksheet. They are having a one-to-one relationship. Sails-postgresql is the adapter I'm using. I'm using waterline orm to fire query to the database. I'm When I am trying to load publications data along with worksheet and then sort the records depending on a field in the Worksheet using sort() I'm getting an error.

My model is:

Publication.js

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
       id: {
          type: 'integer'
          unique: true
        },
        worksheetId: {
          type: 'integer',
          model : 'worksheet'
        },
        status: {
          type: 'string',
          defaultsTo: 'active',
          in : ['active', 'disabled'],
        }
  }
}
```

Worksheet.js

```
module.exports = {
   attributes: {
      id: {
         type: 'integer',
         unique: true
      },
      name: 'string',
      orderWeight: {
         type: 'integer',
         defaultsTo: 0
      }
  }
}
```

So now I want to load all the publication where status is "active" and populate worksheet in the data.

So I'm executing the query:

```
Publication.find({
  where: {
    status: 'active'
  }
})
.populate('worksheetId').limit(1)
.exec(function (error, publications) {
})
```

And I'm getting a data like :

```
{
   id : 1,
   status : "active",
   worksheetId : {
      id : 1
      name : "test",
      orderWeight : 10
   }
}
```

So till now it's all working fine. Now I want to increase the limit to 10 and want to sort the data depending on "orderWeight" which is in the populated data. Initially I sorted the whole data depending on publication id and the query worked.

```
Publication.find({
  where: {
    status: 'active'
  }
})
.populate('worksheetId').sort('id ASC').limit(10)
.exec(function (error, publications) {
})
```

So I fired similar query to sort the data on "orderWeight"

```
Publication.find({
   where: {
      status: 'active'
   }
})
.populate('worksheetId').sort('worksheetId.orderWeight ASC').limit(10)
.exec(function (error, publications) {
})
```

And this query is giving me error that worksheetId.orderWeight is not a column on the publication table. So I want to fire this sort query on the populated data not on the publication table.

Please let me know how I can get my expected result.

Apart from sort() method I also want to run some find command to the populated data to get those publication where the worksheet name matches with certain key as well.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you're trying to do, is query an association's attribute. [This has been in the waterline roadmap since 2014, but it's still not supported](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/266), so you'll have to figure out a workaround.

One option is to query the `Worksheet` model, and populate the `Publication`, since sails doesn't let you query across models without using raw queries (i.e. `.sort('worksheetId.orderWeight ASC')` doesn't work). Unfortunately, you might have to move the `active` flag to the `Worksheet`. For example:

```
Worksheet.find({
  status: 'active'
})
.populate('publication') // you should also add publication to Worksheet.js
.sort('orderWeight ASC')
.limit(10)
```

Alternatively, you could combine `Worksheet` and `Publication` into one model, since they're one-to-one. Probably not ideal, but sails.js and Waterline make it very difficult to work with relational data - I'd estimate that half of the queries in the project I'm working on are raw queries due to sails' poor support of postgres. The framework is pretty biased towards using MongoDB, [although it claims to "just work" with any of the "supported" DBs](http://sailsjs.com/features#?feature-database).